# Nested sums as a single sum

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there a nice way to write the following repeated sum
$$
\sum_{a_1=1}^{i+(2-k)} \sum_{a_2=1}^{i-(a_1-(3-k))}\sum_{a_3=1}^{i-(a_1+a_2-(4-k))}\sum_{a_4=1}^{i-(a_1+a_2+a_3-(5-k))}\dotsb\sum_{a_k=1}^{i-(a_1+a_2+a_3+\dotsb+a_{k-1}-1)} \left[A + \sum_{\ell=0}^{i-(a_1+a_2+\dotsb+a_k)} B_{\ell} + \sum_{p=i-(a_1+a_2+...+a_k-1)}^{i-(a_2+\dotsb+a_k-1)} C_{p} +\dotsb+\sum_{q=i-(a_k-1)}^{i} D_{q} \right],
$$
where $i$ and $k$ are positive integers without any condition (i.e. $i \ge k$ or $k \ge i$),
as a single sum? If any closed form about a few repeated sums can be advised, I will generalize for the rest. Of course, one way is to write it is
$$
\sum_{a_j,1\le j \le k}^{i-(\sum_{\ell=1}^{j-1} a_{\ell}-(j-k+1))},
$$
but I want some appealing form.

Comment: You're missing a summand.

Comment: @SamHopkins, yes, the summand itself is quite complicated involving products and exponentials, which will make my question horrible.

Comment: What do all the tags have to do with the problem?

Comment: So it's the sum over all combinations of $k$ positive (and non-zero, for people who use the French convention) integers which sum to no more than $i+1$?

Comment: The tags should reflect what your question is about, not external context that is irrelevant to the question.  If the external context *is* relevant to the question, then you should include it.  (Also, your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409590/nested-sums-as-a-single-sum#comment1050820_409590) appears to be truncated.)

Comment: @LSpice, I edited the question and added an easy summand.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, Yes, you are right.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer below?

Comment: @losufPinelis, I am trying to understand it fully as this is new for me.

Comment: @AhmedKhan : All right, let me know if you have a question about a specific step in the answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}$For integers $n$ and $k$, let $A_{n,k}$ denote the set of all $a=(a_1,\dots,a_k)\in\N^k$ such that $\sum_1^k a_j\le n$, and let $c_{n,k}$ denote the cardinality of the set $A_{n,k}$.
For $a\in A_{n,k}$, let $s_p:=s_p(a):=\sum_1^p a_j$.

We want to simplify the sum
\begin{equation*}
    \Si:=\sum_{a\in A_{i+1,k}}
\Big(A+\sum_{l=0}^{i-s_k}B_l
+\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\;\sum_{p=i+1-s_k+s_{r-1}}^{i+1-s_k+s_r}C_{r,p}+\sum_{q=i+1-a_k}^i D_q\Big), \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $A,B_l,C_{r,p},D_q$ are arbitrary numbers.
More precisely, we want to (get rid of $\sum_{a\in A_{i+1,k}}$ and) find the coefficients of $A,B_l,C_{r,p},D_q$ in $\Si$. That is, we want to write the identity
\begin{equation*}
    \Si=A\,\Si_A+\sum_{l=0}^{i-k}B_l\,\Si_{B_l}
+\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\;\sum_{p=r-1}^{k-r}C_{r,p}\,\Si_{C_{r,p}}+\sum_{q=k-1}^i D_q\,\Si_{D_q}, \label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where the coefficients $\Si_A,\Si_{B_l},\Si_{C_{r,p}},\Si_{D_q}$ of $A,B_l,C_{r,p},D_q$ do not depend on $A,B_l,C_{r,p},D_q$ -- but only on $i$, $k$, and the respective indices $l,r,p,q$.

The key here is this simple lemma:

> **Lemma 1:** $c_{n,k}=\binom nk$ for any nonnegative integers $n$ and $k$.

This follows by induction, using the recursion
\begin{equation*}
    c_{n,k}=\sum_{a_k=1}^\infty c_{n-a_k,k-1}=\sum_{a_k=1}^{n-(k-1)} c_{n-a_k,k-1}
    =\sum_{j=k-1}^{n-1}c_{j,k-1}. \label{3}\tag{3}
\end{equation*}

It is also easy to give a "bijective" proof of Lemma 1. However, \eqref{3} is more succinct and will be used in what follows.

Immediately from Lemma 1, we get
\begin{equation*}
    \Si_A=c_{i+1,k}=\binom {i+1}k. \label{4}\tag{4}
\end{equation*}

Next, the condition $0\le l\le i-s_k$ on $l$ in \eqref{1} means that $l\ge0$ and $s_k\le i-l$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \Si_{B_l}=\sum_{a\in A_{i+1,k}}1(s_k\le i-l)=c_{i-l,k}=\binom {i-l}k, \label{5}\tag{5}
\end{equation*}
again by Lemma 1.

Further, the condition $i+1-a_k\le q\le i$ on $q$ in (1) means that $q\ge i$ and $a_k\ge i+1-q$. The condition $a\in A_{i+1,k}$ also implies $s_{k-1}\le i+1-a_k$. So, once again by Lemma 1,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \Si_{D_q}&=\sum_{a\in A_{i+1,k}}1(a_k\ge i+1-q,s_{k-1}\le i+1-a_k) \\ 
&=\sum_{a_k=i+1-q}^\infty\binom {i+1-a_k}{k-1}
    =\sum_{j=-\infty}^q\binom j{k-1}
    =\binom {q+1}k;  
\end{aligned}
\label{6}\tag{6}
\end{equation*}
cf. \eqref{3}.

It remains to find $\Si_{C_{r,p}}$. The condition $i+1-s_k+s_{r-1}\le p\le i+1-s_k+s_r$ on $p$ in \eqref{1} together with the condition $a\in A_{i+1,k}$ mean that
\begin{equation*}
    i+1-p-a_r\le \sum_{j=r+1}^k a_j\le\min(i+1-p,i+1-a_r-s_{r-1}). \label{7}\tag{7}
\end{equation*}
Note that $0\le s_{r-1}\le i-k+r$ for $a\in A_{i+1,k}$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \Si_{C_{r,p}}=\sum_{s=0}^{i-k+r}N_{r,s}\Si_{C_{r,p};s}, \label{8}\tag{8}
\end{equation*}
where $N_{r,s}$ is the cardinality of the set of all $(a_1,\dots,a_{r-1})\in\N^{r-1}$ such that $\sum_1^{r-1} a_j=s$, and $\Si_{C_{r,p};s}$ is the cardinality of the set of all $(a_r,\dots,a_k)\in\N^{k-r+1}$ such that inequalities \eqref{7} hold with $s$ in place of $s_{r-1}$.

Note that $N_{r,s}=N_{r,\le s}-N_{r,\le s-1}$, where $N_{r,\le s}$ is the cardinality of the set of all $(a_1,\dots,a_{r-1})\in\N^{r-1}$ such that $\sum_1^{r-1} a_j\le s$. So, $N_{r,\le s}=c_{s,r-1}=\binom s{r-1}$, by Lemma 1. So, $N_{r,s}=\binom s{r-1}-\binom{s-1}{r-1}=\binom{s-1}{r-2}$ if $r\ge2$. However, the equality
\begin{equation*}
    N_{r,s}=\binom{s-1}{r-2} \label{9}\tag{9}
\end{equation*}
holds even for $r=1$. (Alternatively, the case $r=1$ can be similarly considered separately).

Once again by Lemma 1,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\Si_{C_{r,p};s} 
    &=\sum_{a_r=1}^{p-s}\Big(\binom {i+1-p}{k-1}-\binom {i-p-a_r}{k-1}\Big) \\ 
&   +\sum_{a_r=p-s+1}^\infty\Big(\binom {i+1-a_r-s}{k-1}-\binom {i-p-a_r}{k-1}\Big) \\ 
&=(p-s)\binom {i+1-p}{k-1}
+\sum_{j=-\infty}^{i-p}\binom j{k-1} \\ 
&-\sum_{a_r=1}^\infty\binom {i-p-a_r}{k-1} \\ 
&=(p-s)\binom {i+1-p}{k-1}+\binom {i+1-p}k-\binom {i-p}k \\
&=(p-s)\binom {i+1-p}{k-1}+\binom {i-p}{k-1} \\
&=\Big[p\binom {i+1-p}{k-1}+\binom {i-p}{k-1}\Big] -s\binom {i+1-p}{k-1}. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
here we also reasoned as in \eqref{3}.

The latter expression is linear (I mean affine) in $s$. So, in view of \eqref{8} and \eqref{9}, to obtain $\Si_{C_{r,p}}$, it suffices to note that
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{s=1}^{i-k+r}\binom{s-1}{r-2}=\binom {i+1-k+r}{r-1}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{s=1}^{i-k+r}s\binom{s-1}{r-2}
    =(r-1)\sum_{s=1}^{i-k+r}s\binom s{r-1}=(r-1)\binom{i+1-k+r}r. 
\end{equation*}
Collecting the pieces, we finally get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\Si_{C_{r,p}}=\Big[p\binom {i+1-p}{k-1}+\binom {i-p}{k-1}\Big]\binom {i+1-k+r}{r-1} \\ 
    &-(r-1)\binom {i+1-p}{k-1} \binom{i+1-k+r}r. 
\end{aligned} \label{10}\tag{10}
\end{equation*}

Thus, we have \eqref{2} with the coefficients $\Si_A,\Si_{B_l},\Si_{C_{r,p}},\Si_{D_q}$ of $A,B_l,C_{r,p},D_q$ given by \eqref{4}, \eqref{5}, \eqref{6}, \eqref{10}.